# How to hide an image

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I was wondering how you would hide an image in Objective-C. 
I know you can hide text or a button like this

```
    StartGame.hidden = YES;
```

But when I try to do this with an image, i get an error.

Comment: You want to hide the UIImageview the hold the UIImage. For example, UIImageview *imgView = [[UIImageview alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ing.png"]]; then use imgView.hidden = YES which will hide the image

Comment: Can you show the error please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UILabel`, `UIButton`, [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html) and [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_class/reference/reference.html) are all childs from [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) they all have the [`hidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW61) property to hide them.

So any instance of the of a view (or its childs) can be hidden by setting the hidden property to `YES`.

If your [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_class/reference/reference.html) is part of your viewcontroller it would make sense to make a property of it rather then just an variable, but I can not see your full code or error to say that the error might be found there.

Also property or variables should not start with a capital, its not in line with the Objective-C style.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImageView *ImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,width, height)];
    [ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

and to hide this image You just need to write

```
[ImageView setHidden:YES];
```